# Angular UI Router with UI Modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, angular-ui-modal

There are some variations on this question on SO and floating around the web already but they're a bit different and don't have conclusive answers.

Basically, I'd like to change the UI Router state when a modal is opened. Then, I want two things to happen....

A) If the user hits the back button I'd like the modal to be dismissed and the URL to go back to the previous state but without reloading the previous state controller etc. (I just want the overlay and modal removed because the previous state is already underneath the overlay and might have a form which the user is in the process of filling in for instance)/

B) If the user dismisses the modal I'd like the same to happen, the URL should change back to the previous one (the modal could have been opened from anywhere so we can't hard code the state that it will return to) and the modal should close.

(A) can almost be solved by using this code...

```
App.run([
  '$rootScope', '$modalStack', 
  function($rootScope, $modalStack) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function() {
      var top = $modalStack.getTop();
      if (top) {
        $modalStack.dismiss(top.key);
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

but that will close the modal even if opening another popup on top of the current one (because it doesn't know if we're moving forward or backwards). Basically we want to say "has the user hit the back button or has the state transitioned ot the previous state, if so, close the top modal).

(B) I'm not sure how to solve. We could force a state change back to the previous state when the modal is dismissed (If we knew what the previous state was), but the code for (A) above would then get triggered and possibly remove another modal from the stack. Also, the previous state would get re-initiated. Basically we want to just want to go back to the previous URL when the modal is closed, but without doing a full state change, if that makes sense?

Like I say, there are some semi solutions out there, but nothing which seems to handle the above scenarios. Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: curious what use case is for needing route change for modal. Users are accustomed to closing modals without using back button

Comment: It's a responsive site and on mobile the modal fills the whole screen and looks like a new screen. If they're on search results and open a product then hitting the back button would go to the previous page of results (and not actually close the window anyway, double confusion).

Comment: ok...makes sense. ui-router has facilities to store controller state but another way would be use `search` and option setting for `reloadOnSearch:false`. *not sure if that is exact property name*

Comment: I'll investigate that. Thanks.